# Explain like I'm 5 — EMM, MDM, UEM

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Server Fault post: [Explain like I'm 5 — EMM, MDM, UEM](https://serverfault.com/questions/1053043/explain-like-im-5-emm-mdm-uem)

I posted this question here because I saw your MDM tag. Why's my question off topic? Apology.

Answer (score 7):

This site is for professional system administrators, very few of whom are likely to be five years old.  Also, we don't really do "explainers", because they're not a good fit for a question-and-answer format -- they tend to require "essay length" answers, at the very least, and tend to breed a lot of discussion and "OK but what about..." extension questions in comments, which again isn't how things work here.  Finally, we also don't do hypotheticals -- all questions should be based on a real world business problem you are currently facing.